# How can I tell if two elements on the same page have the same ID?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a component which will be running on foreign sites.
How can I tell if a specific ID appears more than once on the page?
I need to know this in order to make sure that an element which is supplied to me "from the outside" is unique in that sense.

I have tried identifying this using both document.getElementById and document.querySelector, but both seem to return the first element with the non unique ID, rather than both.
jQuery and Sizzle were no help either, as they use those very same methods.

Comment: when i have created plugins i create a unique id and then reference that id, only if its a javascript plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using jQuery you could use an attribute selector rather than the id selector:

```
$("[id='someId']")
```

which should return all elements with that Id

---

**Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/VvX7r/**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying the whole page of elements, you could also do similar to:

```
function isUniqueId( selector ) {
var elm = $(selector).get(0),
    prevId = elm.id,
    isUnique;

elm.id = "temp"+(+new Date);

isUnique = !$(selector).length;

    if( prevId ) {
    elm.id = prevId;
    }


return isUnique;
}
```

If you're attaching it to anyone's page, performance should be a concern.

Comment: +1 Though I'd consider using `getElementById` so the solution isn't dependent on jQuery.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, yea it's pretty bad it also fails if the id isn't found (trying to get .id of undefined) :P if it gets more appreciation I might just refactor it :D

Answer (score 0):

IDs are supposed to be unique so you won't find many tools that help you there.

Have you tried iterating recursively over every single element in the DOM and checking the id?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for Sizzle, but because Jquery uses CSS selectors in its methods to return Dom objects. By its nature the id of an element should be unique. So in this implementation JQuery is correct in returning only the first result it finds, as there should only be one.

However I see your quandry in that you can't control what gets put into your page from external sources.

In this case, short of parsing each HTML element to check for duplicates I don't see any other option.

Answer (score 0):

I got this snippet form SO a while ago, i cant rember where? It's for use with FF `firebug console`. you might beable to adapt it.

```
(function () {
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i, len, ids = {}, id;
for (i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    id = elms[i].id || null;
    if (id) {
        ids[id] =  ids.hasOwnProperty(id) ? ids[id] +=1 : 0;
    }
}
for (id in ids) {
    if (ids.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        if (ids[id]) {
            console.warn("Multiple IDs #" + id);
        }
    }
}
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var id =  "test1",
    elems = [];

 while ( d = document.getElementById(id) ) {
    elems.push( d );
    d.removeAttribute("id")
}

for ( i in elems ) {
    elems[i].setAttribute("id",id);
}

console.log (elems);
```

but `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` aren't crossbrowser.
The easiest way is to use jQuery selector by attributes `[]` as in `hunter`'s answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that `querySelector` will only return the first match. Try `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id');
```